# cakephp szajbus uploadpack - image doesn't show because self::$__settings array is empty

Tags: cakephp, plugins, upload

I have 2 views, **postview.ctp** and **usercomment.ctp**, calling the same **comment.ctp** element. This element shows image using UploadPack helper. But image on **usercomment.ctp** doesn't show and has this error message

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP\Plugin\upload_pack\Model\Behavior\UploadBehavior.php, line 222] 

line 222: $settings = self::$__settings[$modelName][$field];
```

The self::$__settings in **usercomment.ctp** is empty , but in **postview.ctp** it's not empty and the image showed up correctly.

comment.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->upload->image(
    $comment['User'], 
    'User.avatar',
    array('style' => 'thumb'),  
    array('class' => array('img-responsive', 'img-rounded'))
), 
array('controller' => 'users', 
      'action' => 'view', 
      $comment['User']['id']),
      array('escape' => false) 
) ?>
```

And this is code to call comment.ctp on from the both view.

```
<?php if (!empty($comments)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?> 
        <?php echo $this->element('comment',array('comment' => $comment));?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've checked the $comment array and they're identical. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load User model on usercomment action in Comment controller.

```
public function usercomments($id) {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    if($this->Auth->loggedIn()){
    .....
```